# In Unity, the scene doesn't change when the button is pressed, and the text is not appearing on the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, the scene doesn't change when the button is pressed, and the text is not appearing on the screen.

I'm making a prime number game in Unity. However, for some reason, when click the button in the game, it doesn't start(and the same happens when I press any key), and the text that should appear on the screen is not displaying.

If the number is taken from "asal.txt" and the player presses the green button, they will earn 1 point. If they press the red button, they will lose 1 point. If the number is taken from "değil.txt" and the player presses the no button, they will earn 1 point. If they press red button, they should lose 1 point. The score and the number should be displayed on the screen but its not working

The game consist of two scenes, and I'm writing the scripts. I'm using C#

I tried looking at chatgpt something but it didn't work

Start menu scripts:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BaslangicMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public OyunScript oyunScript; // OyunScript referansý

    public void NormalModButtonClick()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Normal Modd");
    }

}
```

Game script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OyunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text sayiText; // Text bileþeni referansý
    public Text puanText; // Puaný gösteren Text bileþeni referansý

    private string[] asalSayilar;
    private string[] degilSayilar;

    private int puan = 0;
    private int index = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        asalSayilar = File.ReadAllLines("asal.txt");
        degilSayilar = File.ReadAllLines("degil.txt");

        YeniSayiAl();
        GuncellePuanText();
    }

    public void YeniSayiAl()
    {
        // Metotun içeriði
    }

    public void EvetButtonClick()
    {
        int sayi = int.Parse(asalSayilar[index]);
        if (IsAsal(sayi))
        {
            puan += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            puan -= 1;
        }

        YeniSayiAl();
        GuncellePuanText();
    }

    public void HayirButtonClick()
    {
        int sayi = int.Parse(asalSayilar[index]);
        if (!IsAsal(sayi))
        {`your text`
            puan += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            puan -= 1;
        }

        YeniSayiAl();
        GuncellePuanText();
    }

    private bool IsAsal(int sayi)
    {
        if (sayi < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i * i <= sayi; i++)
        {
            if (sayi % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void GuncellePuanText()
    {
        puanText.text = "Puan: " + puan.ToString();
    }
}
```

I used chatgpt but broke my game. I did some research but still it didn't work. Where ist he error in my code? and why isn't fixed?